# How to Delete part of text in all items Listview android?

Tags: android, listview

I have list of directory and list in listview

[image]

I want remove part of text in all items  00 3-0 rec  delele from items.

Comment: The image you added is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to format your text in your adapter for the list view.

[You can do it in getView of your adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Use yourString.replace("00 3-0",""); in getView or in your List of items by iterating through them.

[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Change this

list.add(m.group(1));

to

list.add((m.group(1)).replace("00 3-0",""));

Comment: how change my code to correct replace("00 3-0","");     private void fill_SUbDirectory() {
  lst_sub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  lst_sub.requestFocus();
  String html = resString;
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     while (m.find()) {
                        System.out.println(m.group(1));
                       list.add(m.group(1));
   }
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.listview_header_row_sub2, list);
  lst_sub.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  

 }

Comment: Changed the answer please see that.

Comment: private void fill_SUbDirectory() { lst_sub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); lst_sub.requestFocus(); String html = resString; Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>"); Matcher m = p.matcher(html); List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); while (m.find()) { System.out.println(m.group(1)); list.add((m.group(1)).replace("00 3-0","")); } ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_header_row_sub2, list); lst_sub.setAdapter(dataAdapter); }